# Is it possible to link url with a tag using not 'href' but 'data-link' attribute?

Tags: html, attributes, href

I thought I can only use 'href' attribute to link url in a tag but I found the following example.

```
<a data-link="https://stackoverflow.com/" style="cursor: pointer" class="custom-sub-controller" data-id="application27" data-pid="application">link</a>
```

Is it possible to link url with a tag using not 'href' but 'data-link' attribute?

Comment: No. It's just data for JavaScript and other programming languages to play with. It doesn't have any intrinsic meaning.

Comment: @Quentin Then how is it possible to connect to linked url? There are no 'href' attribute. It only has 'data-link' attribute. But it works.

Comment: Presumably some JS on the page uses that data.

Comment: @Quentin Maybe you're right. Then I should find the function that use the data. But the thing is the code is not mine. Can I see all JS code on website using f12(developer mode) on chrome?